# lenguaje C: Debugger con un fichero de entrada como parámetro del depurador

Tags: c, ide, vscode, depuración

Tengo un programa escrito en C que lo compilo con el comando "gcc nombrePrograma.c -o nombreEjecutable". Una vez generado el fichero ejecutable hago las pruebas mediante el comando "nombreEjecutable < casosPrueba.in" .

Necesitaria un IDE con un depurador que le pueda configurar el fichero de entrada "casosPrueba.in".

Estoy probandolo en Visual Studio Code pero no sé como indicarle un fichero de entrada al debugger. ¿Alguien ha hecho algo similar aunque sea con otro entorno? 
¡¡Gracias por adelantado!!

Comment: [esto](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20890) puede ayudarte. Como alternativa yo abriría el archivo como un `FILE *` en el programa y pasaría la ruta del archivo `casosPrueba.in` como un argumento en el archivo `launch.json`, no tengo VSCode a mano para buscar otra solución, pero debería funcionar así.

Comment: Lo pensé, pero me toca cambiar todas las funciones de lectura de valores a lo largo del programa. Mi programa es un programa que intenta resolver uno de los retos de www.aceptaelreto.com , en concreto: https://www.aceptaelreto.com/problem/statement.php?id=476&cat=117 . Realmente ya lo pude resolver, pero como digo, me resultaría interesante tener un mejor sistema de traza que no tuviera que tocar nada de la aplicación hecha para cuando se me vuelva a presentar un problema que quiera depurar. Estoy seguro que con el Visual Studio Code u otro IDE se puede hacer, falta saber como.